# Call multiple macro using array and function in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am unable to call macros whose names I have stored in a String Array.

I attach the code.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Dim i, Ro As Integer

Public Sub Universal_Macro()

Dim Col(10) As Integer
Dim macro_name(10) As String

Ro = ActiveCell.Row

i = 1

For i = 1 To 10
    Call Mac_Sched(Col(), macro_name())
Next

End Sub

Sub Mac_Sched(Col() As Integer, Internal_Array() As String)
    Cells(Ro, Col(i)).Select
    Call Internal_Array(i)
End Sub
```

Getting error in the `sub Mac_Sched`.

Comment: You didn't qualify `cells` or pass `i`.

Comment: getting error here Call Internal_Array(i) it says expected sub or function or property

Comment: You cannot `Call` a string. Try looking at at `CallByName`

Comment: Can you please eloberate I am very novice with vba or excel vba

Comment: @findwindow - `i` will work in this instance since it's Dimensioned outside the scope of any particular procedure.

Comment: Good call. Didn't catch that.

Comment: Can I please have a solution

Comment: Did you look up what Tim said? Don't make me regret my upvote XD

Comment: okey this is how we do it Application.Run (Internal_Array(i)) in the called sub and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **Application.Run**:

```
Sub RunMc()

 Dim a(1 To 2) As String
 Dim MN As String

 For i = 1 To 2 'Fill the array
  a(i) = "m" & i
 Next
 MN = "Module1" 'the module name

 For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
  Application.Run MN & "." & a(i)
 Next

End Sub

Sub m1()
 Debug.Print "m1"
End Sub

Sub m2()
 Debug.Print "m2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

TBBH, I really don't know what you are trying to accomplish and the heavily redacted code does nothing to show specific methods other than the attempt at calling a macro from a string derived from an array element.

The [Application.OnTime method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx) uses a string as the name of the procedure to call.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Dim i As Integer, Ro As Integer

Sub zero()
    Debug.Print "zero: " & i
End Sub

Sub first()
    Debug.Print "first: " & i
End Sub

Sub second()
    Debug.Print "second: " & i
End Sub

Sub third()
    Debug.Print "third: " & i
End Sub

Public Sub Universal_Macro()
    Dim Col() As Integer
    Dim macro_Name As Variant


    macro_Name = Array("zero", "first", "second", "third")
    ReDim Col(UBound(macro_Name))
    For i = LBound(macro_Name) To UBound(macro_Name)
        Col(i) = i
    Next

    Ro = ActiveCell.Row

    For i = LBound(macro_Name) To UBound(macro_Name)
        Call macro_Sched(Col(i), macro_Name)
    Next

End Sub

Sub macro_Sched(c As Integer, internal_Array As Variant)
    Cells(Ro, c + 1).Select '<~~Don't rely on Select! You dont' even reference a worksheet here.
    Application.OnTime Now, internal_Array(c)
End Sub
```

If parameters were to be passed to the children sub procedures, then some sort of string replacement might accommodate this but specifics on the child subs are not evident.

---

<sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>